# How to extract model file(s) from Vertex AI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have been trying to import model file(s) from Vertex AI to Workbench environment. My pipeline consists of preprocessing, training and batch predictions. Sometimes the training fails due to unknown reasons yet I want the batch predictions from the latest model in that case. Is there a way to access the trained models using Python?